# ordering a gremlinpipeline in java

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop

javadoc :
   order(com.tinkerpop.pipes.PipeFunction,Integer> compareFunction)
Add an OrderPipe to the end of the Pipeline.

```
        new GremlinPipeline<>()
            .start(vtag)
            .out(GraphHelper.EDGE_TYPE_OWNERSHIP, GraphHelper.EDGE_TYPE_PARTICIPATION)
            .has("status",Activity.STATUS_OPEN)
            .order(new PipeFunction<Pair<? extends Element, ? extends Element>, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer compute(Pair<? extends Element, ? extends Element> argument) {
                    Long ret = (Long.parseLong(argument.getA().getProperty("postDate"))
                            - Long.parseLong(argument.getB().getProperty("postDate")));
                    return ret.intValue();
                }
            })
            .range(start, start + size)
            .iterator().forEachRemaining(v ->
        activities.add(getActivity(v.getId().toString(), null, AccessType.OWNER, false))
    );
```

while I can see my ide proposing the method and it is in the javadocs, I get an error when compiling that no suitable method was found.

where is the mistake?